# Assigning one semaphore to other

Tags: c, semaphore, vxworks

Can I assign one sempahore to other semaphore, will both behave as the same, for eg.(this vxworks code)

```
   mySemId = semCreate(...)
       tempSemId = mySemId;
    semTake(tempSemId,...);
   ...
   semGive(mySemId).
```

will the above code snippet work in locking the resource.

Secondly, if this works is there a coding standard or practice that does not allow this kind of processing.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: I m not doing this, i understand it should not be done. just want to know is there some standard that forbids it as C does not.

Comment: That is a question for your local coding standards. There is no reason why this can't be done, but if I saw this in a code review i might query it, but it depends on the context. For instance, if the SEM_ID was buried deep in a nested struct, i might prefer to assign to a temp just to shorten it

Comment: But, I would then expect the take and give to use the same name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

vxWorks semaphore IDs are copyable, and the copy is "just as good" as the original, so the code sample shown here is not wrong.  It does not seem a particularly good idea, though.  It's hard to tell from this snippet what the entire code looks like, and in a larger block of code, I think it would be difficult to tell which semaphore(s) are being Taken and which are being Given.

(This is not a C language question: vxWorks semaphores are mainly usable *from* C, but are not *defined by* the language.)